# Notification large icon always green robot

Tags: android

I try to show notification using NotificationCompat.Builder:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_small);
builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_notification_large));
builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.push_notification_received_title));
builder.setContentText("message");

((NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
        .notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

But, instead large icon that I pointed on the builder in notification I get icon with a green robot (default icon like ic_luncher). I suppose problem may be that I use xiaomi device, but some applications like google translate show normal large icon.

Comment: R.drawable.ic_notification_large its own image or system?

Comment: R.drawable.ic_notification_large is own icon

Comment: Are you sure you set good format for this icon?

Comment: I have faced the same situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some of time I found a problem. Some of the shell (such as xiaomi) get large notification icon from launcher icon, so need to change launcher icon, reinstall application and reboot device for the changes to take effect (because icons placed in the cache).